# Continuous X variables and ordinal discrete Y variable. Which X variable is better predictor of y variable. Which tests to use for this

Tags: regression, statistical-significance

I am trying to understand which is the better predictor for customer satisfaction score. Is it the first response time or the final response tike taken.
Customer satisfaction score is ordinal discrete values 1,2,3,4 & 5.
Both the input variables are continuous data.
Which test would be the be the best to predict this.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ordinal response model such as the proportional odds semiparametric ordinal logistic regression model.   When judging variable importance use its likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ statistic.  But use the bootstrap to get a confidence interval for the importance ranks as often variable importance is hard to nail down.  Also don't assume the predictors are linear.   Much more on this may be found in [RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rms).